# How to make Apache rewrite blog URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I've installed WAMP, made an alias, and put into that folder a ".htaccess" file. My goal is to have a URL such as "foo.com/blog/bar-baz" internally call "display.php?name=bar-baz". Among various things I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ display.php?$1
```

However, this gives a "The requested URL /Users/.../public/display.php was not found on this server". Playing around I was able to get this to work:

```
RewriteRule ^blog.php$ /personal/display.php
```

Advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule from root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /personal/display.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Another related question: is it possible for me to get rid of the "personal" string so that the ".htaccess" will be portable?

Comment: Well if you have kept `display.php` in `/personal/` directory then you will have to use that in rewrite rule. You can remove `/personal/` only if you move `display.php` a level above to `DirectoryRoot`.

Comment: I can't do it because "personal" is just an alias. Internally it points to "c:\Users\...\Desktop\web\public".

Comment: Either way, rewrite rules would need to route to `display.php` with correct path only.

Comment: I took some time to see if it's possible to avoid "hardcoding" the alias name in the ".htaccess" file but did not find. The only thing that I found that makes it feel better than a hack is the "RewriteBase" directive. Unfortunately, I'll need to make the .htaccess file ignorable by the source control system and just have a ".htaccess.sample" so physically copy and change the alias.